# Output two viewbag values in one embedded code block

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have the following code for my HomeController.cs

```
ViewBag.Test = "hi there";
ViewBag.Message = "sausages";
```

and then I return View();

In my aspx page, I reference ViewBag.Message like this:

```
<h2><%:ViewBag.Message %></h2>
```

How do I go about doing something like ( I know it makes no sense to but... )

```
<% ViewBag.Message; ViewBag.Test %>
```

?

In order to output: sausages hi there

Comment: And what is the expected output of this invented code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking how to concatenate strings:

```
<%: ViewBag.Message + ViewBag.Test %>
```

You may also want a space.

Comment: Could have sworn I tried that ^_^. Thanks.. must have been me being a noob.